trouble sending tron transaction with tronapi python
I'm trying to send TRON to an address and I get an error "Invalid amount provided"
    amount_sun = int(amount * 1_000_000)

    txn = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, lambda: tron.trx.send_transaction(to_address, amount_sun ))
    print(f"Transaction: {txn}")

    trans_link = f'https://tronscan.org/#/transaction/{txn.get("txid")}'
    return trans_link

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")`

